# Awkward Silence

Tags: film-sound-design

I've always tried to remember the sounds during such a circumstance but never found an opportunity to use it, but these guys have! Have a look at this clip from Margin Call that has been re-edited [Margin Call Awkward Silence](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MRoF25gPAg&feature=share). Awesome stuff.

[youtube]9MRoF25gPAg[/youtube]

Answer (score 1):

I'm the editor and sound designer from that video... Practically the entire scene was constructed sound-wise, since all of the reaction shots had people talking over them.  I took original room ambience and a small smattering of sounds from the original scene, then added a generous helping of coughs, phone buzzes, etc.  The ice cream truck sound I procured from the internet, but it didn't sound right at full speed so it was slowed.  Much of the material came from stock sound libraries, including the chair squeaks and leather shuffling.  The stomach gurgling was from one of a disturbing number of women recording their digestion and posting it to YouTube.  There is only one thing that I had to create myself...  there was no clean source material available to me for mouth sounds.  Every lip smack, mouth opening and closing is actually me and my trusty condenser mic.  To make it all gel as a cohesive whole, I applied reverb to the whole thing to make the room sound even more empty and make all of the foley sound as if they occupy the same space.

Comment: Very cool, I totally thought a lot of that came from the production! Cheers

Comment: This was freaking awesome, sucks it came down.

Comment: But I have one burning question: Who did the "um"s of the young man who stands up???!?!

Answer (score 0):

Starts with good acting performances, film editing, clever mix of prod dial track and tasteful Foley/Sfx. Thanks for sharing! Fun moment indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Shame this vid is no longer online due to copyright reasons, would've "dug" to have a  look / listen after reading Kilna's breakdown...

Comment: Same here. Kilna, could you share your work again, please?

Comment: for their sakes I hope the producers pay them to put it onto the dvd. but if possible, I would love to get my hands on a copy of the video too. Really good resource for teaching.

Answer (score 0):

The video is back online, it was removed errantly by Lion's Gate, I think their IP enforcer mistook it for the original scene (probably by only skipping through it and not paying attention).  @Utopia: that's the original actor's "uhhhh", there is are only a few bits where I used original source audio, that's one of them.  He does "ummm" a few times in the scene.